# How to copy graph properties of one boost graph into another boost graph?

Tags: c++, boost, c++17, boost-graph

I have a boost graph with vertex , edge and graph properties. I want to make a copy of boost braph. I copied vertex and edge properties ( using `copy_graph`) of one boost graph into another one but could not able to copy graph properties.

```
using BGType = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS,
                                     // Vertex Properties...
                                     vertexProps,
                                     // Edge Propereties...
                                     edgeProps,
                                     // Graph Properties
                                     graphProps>;
```

I have graph properties :

```
class graphProps {
   public:
    explicit graphProps(std::string *name = nullptr) { _name = name ? *name : ""; };

    std::string _name;
    std::map<std::string, std::tuple<std::vector<schPinInfo *>,  // input Pins
                                     std::vector<schPinInfo *>,  // inout pins
                                     std::vector<schPinInfo *>>  // output pins
             >
      _modInfo;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> _altNames;
    std::map<std::string, schSymbol> _modSymbol;
}
```

```
struct CustomVertexCopy {
    BGType const& g1;
    BGType&       g2;

    void operator()(BGType::vertex_descriptor v1, BGType::vertex_descriptor v2) const {
        vertexProps const& p1 = g1[v1];
        vertexProps&       p2 = g2[v2];

        p2._refPtr     = p1._refPtr;
        p2._moduleName = p1._moduleName;
        p2._name       = p1._name;
    }
};

struct CustomEdgeCopy {
    BGType const& g1;
    BGType&       g2;

    void operator()(BGType::edge_descriptor e1, BGType::edge_descriptor e2) const {
        g2[e2]._name = g1[e1]._name;
    }
};
```

my copy_graph is like this :

```
OnClick(BGType* bGraph)
{
   // some code
   BGType* oldBg = new BGType;
   boost::copy_graph(*bGraph, *oldBg,
                      boost::vertex_copy(CustomVertexCopy{*bGraph,*oldBg})
                            .edge_copy(CustomEdgeCopy{*bGraph, *oldBg}));
   // some code
}
```

How to copy grap properties ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

- `boost::copy_graph` doesn't support it.
- just copy assigning it will be fine:

  ```
  boost::get_property(g2) = boost::get_property(g1)
  ```

Adapted from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160746/85371) with demo:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90e74c2581a2c47f)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

class vertexProps {
  public:
    vertexProps(vertexProps const&)            = default;
    vertexProps& operator=(vertexProps const&) = default;

    explicit vertexProps(std::string mn = {}, std::string n = {}, long refPtr = 0)
        : _moduleName(std::move(mn))
        , _name(std::move(n))
        , _refPtr(refPtr) {}

    std::string _moduleName;
    std::string _name;
    long        _refPtr;
};

class edgeProps {
  public:
    edgeProps(edgeProps const&)            = default;
    edgeProps& operator=(edgeProps const&) = default;
    explicit edgeProps(std::string name = "") : _name(name){};

    std::string _name;
};

struct schPinInfo { std::string id; };
schPinInfo const wellknownPins[] = {
    {"i1"}, {"i2"}, {"i3"}, {"o4"}, {"o5"}, {"i6"}, {"i7"}, {"i8"}, {"o9"}, {"o10"},
};

static schPinInfo const* const i1  = wellknownPins + 0;
static schPinInfo const* const i2  = wellknownPins + 1;
static schPinInfo const* const i3  = wellknownPins + 2;
static schPinInfo const* const o4  = wellknownPins + 3;
static schPinInfo const* const o5  = wellknownPins + 4;
static schPinInfo const* const i6  = wellknownPins + 5;
static schPinInfo const* const i7  = wellknownPins + 6;
static schPinInfo const* const i8  = wellknownPins + 7;
static schPinInfo const* const o9  = wellknownPins + 8;
static schPinInfo const* const o10 = wellknownPins + 9;

using Pins = std::vector<schPinInfo const*>;
struct Layout {
    Pins input, inout, output;
};
struct schSymbol {};

struct graphProps {
    graphProps& operator=(graphProps const&) = default;
    explicit graphProps(std::string name = {}) : _name(std::move(name)) {}

    std::string                                     _name;
    std::map<std::string, Layout>                   _modInfo;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> _altNames;
    std::map<std::string, schSymbol>                _modSymbol;
};

using BGType = boost::adjacency_list<                //
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, //
    vertexProps, edgeProps, graphProps>;

int main() {
    BGType g2;

    {
        BGType g1{3, graphProps{"name"}};
        {
            boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo = {
                {"mod1", Layout{{i1, i2, i3}, {}, {o4, o5}}},
                {"mod2", Layout{{i6, i7, i8}, {}, {o9, o10}}},
            };
            boost::get_property(g1)._altNames = {
                {"mod1", {"MOD1", "MOD_1"}},
                {"mod2", {"MOD2", "MOD_2"}},
            };
            boost::get_property(g1)._modSymbol = {
                {"mod1", schSymbol{}},
                {"mod2", schSymbol{}},
            };

            g1[0] = vertexProps{"Hello", "world", 111};
            g1[1] = vertexProps{"Goodbye", "moon", 222};
            g1[2] = vertexProps{"Greetings", "Cosmos", 333};

            add_edge(0, 1, edgeProps{"one"}, g1);
            add_edge(2, 0, edgeProps{"two"}, g1);
        }

        g2 = g1; // FULL COPY
        // copy_graph(g1, g2); // doesn't copy graph property
    }

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g2));
    dp.property("moduleName", get(&vertexProps::_moduleName, g2));
    dp.property("name", get(&vertexProps::_name, g2));
    dp.property("ref", get(&vertexProps::_refPtr, g2));
    dp.property("name", get(&edgeProps::_name, g2));
    dp.property("name", get(&edgeProps::_name, g2));
    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g2, dp);

    fmt::print("Copied _altNames: {}\n", boost::get_property(g2)._altNames);
}
```

Prints

```
digraph G {
0 [moduleName=Hello, name=world, ref=111];
1 [moduleName=Goodbye, name=moon, ref=222];
2 [moduleName=Greetings, name=Cosmos, ref=333];
0->1  [name=one, name=one];
2->0  [name=two, name=two];
}
Copied _altNames: {"mod1": ["MOD1", "MOD_1"], "mod2": ["MOD2", "MOD_2"]}
```

### Deep Cloning Dynamic Data

What if you expected the `schPinInfo` objects to be deep copied as well? To correctly do object tracking so that repeated pins will not be (de)serialized  more than once, I suggest Boost Serialization:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52cb3b40bcd7d87f)**

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adj_list_serialize.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

class vertexProps {
  public:
    vertexProps(vertexProps const&)            = default;
    vertexProps& operator=(vertexProps const&) = default;

    explicit vertexProps(std::string mn = {}, std::string n = {}, long refPtr = 0)
        : _moduleName(std::move(mn))
        , _name(std::move(n))
        , _refPtr(refPtr) {}

    std::string _moduleName;
    std::string _name;
    long        _refPtr;
};

class edgeProps {
  public:
    edgeProps(edgeProps const&)            = default;
    edgeProps& operator=(edgeProps const&) = default;
    explicit edgeProps(std::string name = "") : _name(name){};

    std::string _name;
};

struct schPinInfo { std::string id; };
schPinInfo const wellknownPins[] = {
    {"i1"}, {"i2"}, {"i3"}, {"o4"}, {"o5"}, {"i6"}, {"i7"}, {"i8"}, {"o9"}, {"o10"},
};

static schPinInfo const* const i1  = wellknownPins + 0;
static schPinInfo const* const i2  = wellknownPins + 1;
static schPinInfo const* const i3  = wellknownPins + 2;
static schPinInfo const* const o4  = wellknownPins + 3;
static schPinInfo const* const o5  = wellknownPins + 4;
static schPinInfo const* const i6  = wellknownPins + 5;
static schPinInfo const* const i7  = wellknownPins + 6;
static schPinInfo const* const i8  = wellknownPins + 7;
static schPinInfo const* const o9  = wellknownPins + 8;
static schPinInfo const* const o10 = wellknownPins + 9;

using Pins = std::vector<schPinInfo const*>;
struct Layout {
    Pins input, inout, output;
};
struct schSymbol {};

struct graphProps {
    graphProps& operator=(graphProps const&) = default;
    explicit graphProps(std::string name = {}) : _name(std::move(name)) {}

    std::string                                     _name;
    std::map<std::string, Layout>                   _modInfo;
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> _altNames;
    std::map<std::string, schSymbol>                _modSymbol;
};

using BGType = boost::adjacency_list<                //
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, //
    vertexProps, edgeProps, graphProps>;

void serialize(auto& ar, vertexProps& p, unsigned) { ar& p._moduleName& p._name& p._refPtr;              } 
void serialize(auto& ar, edgeProps& p, unsigned)   { ar& p._name;                                        } 
void serialize(auto& ar, graphProps& p, unsigned)  { ar& p._name& p._modInfo& p._altNames& p._modSymbol; } 
void serialize(auto&, schSymbol&, unsigned)        {                                                     } 
void serialize(auto& ar, schPinInfo& i, unsigned)  { ar& i.id;                                           } 
void serialize(auto& ar, Layout& l, unsigned)      { ar& l.input& l.inout& l.output;                     } 

BGType deep_copy(BGType const& g1) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive(ss) << g1;

    BGType g2;
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive(ss) >> g2; 
    return g2;
}

int main() {
    BGType g2;

    {
        BGType g1{3, graphProps{"name"}};
        {
            boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo = {
                {"mod1", Layout{{i1, i2, i3}, {}, {o4, o5}}},
                {"mod2", Layout{{i6, i7, i8}, {}, {o9, o10}}},
            };
            boost::get_property(g1)._altNames = {
                {"mod1", {"MOD1", "MOD_1"}},
                {"mod2", {"MOD2", "MOD_2"}},
            };
            boost::get_property(g1)._modSymbol = {
                {"mod1", schSymbol{}},
                {"mod2", schSymbol{}},
            };

            g1[0] = vertexProps{"Hello", "world", 111};
            g1[1] = vertexProps{"Goodbye", "moon", 222};
            g1[2] = vertexProps{"Greetings", "Cosmos", 333};

            add_edge(0, 1, edgeProps{"one"}, g1);
            add_edge(2, 0, edgeProps{"two"}, g1);

            assert(boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo["mod2"].input.at(0) == i6);
            assert(boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo["mod2"].input.at(1) == i7);
            assert(boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo["mod2"].input.at(2) == i8);
            assert(boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo["mod2"].output.at(0) == o9);
            assert(boost::get_property(g1)._modInfo["mod2"].output.at(1) == o10);
        }

        g2 = deep_copy(g1); // even deeply copied schPinInfo const* objects!

        assert(boost::get_property(g2)._modInfo["mod2"].input.at(0) != i6);
        assert(boost::get_property(g2)._modInfo["mod2"].input.at(1) != i7);
        assert(boost::get_property(g2)._modInfo["mod2"].input.at(2) != i8);
        assert(boost::get_property(g2)._modInfo["mod2"].output.at(0) != o9);
        assert(boost::get_property(g2)._modInfo["mod2"].output.at(1) != o10);
    }

    boost::dynamic_properties dp;
    dp.property("node_id", get(boost::vertex_index, g2));
    dp.property("moduleName", get(&vertexProps::_moduleName, g2));
    dp.property("name", get(&vertexProps::_name, g2));
    dp.property("ref", get(&vertexProps::_refPtr, g2));
    dp.property("name", get(&edgeProps::_name, g2));
    dp.property("name", get(&edgeProps::_name, g2));
    write_graphviz_dp(std::cout, g2, dp);

    fmt::print("Copied _altNames: {}\n", boost::get_property(g2)._altNames);

    // note the deeply allocated schPinInfo are leaked!
}
```

Printing

```
digraph G {
0 [moduleName=Hello, name=world, ref=111];
1 [moduleName=Goodbye, name=moon, ref=222];
2 [moduleName=Greetings, name=Cosmos, ref=333];
0->1  [name=one, name=one];
2->0  [name=two, name=two];
}
Copied _altNames: {"mod1": ["MOD1", "MOD_1"], "mod2": ["MOD2", "MOD_2"]}
```

Notes:

- the assertions all pass - making the deepcloned `schPinInfo` tangible.
- the deserialized instanced of `schPinInfo` are now leaked, which is why you should not be using raw pointers:

  ```
  ==794912==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

  Direct leak of 320 byte(s) in 10 object(s) allocated from:
      #0 0x7f11ffec21e7 in operator new(unsigned long) ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_new_delete.cpp:99
      #1 0x55698a066997 in boost::archive::detail::heap_allocation<schPinInfo>::doesnt_have_new_operator::invoke_new() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:243
      #2 0x55698a066997 in boost::archive::detail::heap_allocation<schPinInfo>::invoke_new() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:257
      #3 0x55698a066997 in boost::archive::detail::heap_allocation<schPinInfo>::heap_allocation() /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:270
      #4 0x55698a066997 in boost::archive::detail::pointer_iserializer<boost::archive::binary_iarchive, schPinInfo>::heap_allocation() const /home/sehe/custom/superboost/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:295

  SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 320 byte(s) leaked in 10 allocation(s).
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Your `boost::get_property(g2) = boost::get_property(g1)` solution worked.  But it is crashing after some time. Seems that schPinInfo did not get copy properly.  So I tried your serialization/deserialization way but it is tough for me to understand it.  So cant we copy schPinInfo data manually ?

Comment: You certainly can. I'm not going to assist until I understand what you need/use these raw pointers for / like (that's why I suggested boost serialization which knows how to track unique objects and aliased pointers. It is pretty advanced). It's not even obvious to me that your crashes would be solved by it! There's enough code smells surrounding threading and memory management that can easily explain the manifestation of undefined behavior

Comment: I strongly suggest to wrap all your indirection with e.g. smart pointers and just give your properties value semantics so that `g2 = g1;` just efficiently does what you expect without all the unnecessary complexity.

Comment: I have a schematic which contains rectangles, lines, circles. All these are stored in boost graph. This schematic can be increased ( Incremental schematic). If I click on pin, whatever connected to pin, gets visible ( i.e. it gets added in boost graph and the displayed)  Now here I want to add `undo-redo` feature. In `undo` I will use previous state of boost graph and draw it. And in `redo`  I will use new state of boost graph ( means state after clicking, which will have more object in boost graph )

Comment: So in Click() function, I am storing the boost graph as old boost graph. Then adding some object into it. That is my new boost graph.  `undo` will use old one and `redo` will use new one to draw.  That's why I am copying boost graph into another boost graph. But now got stuck at copying `Graph properties`. I am drawing boost graph element using Qt framework.

Comment: I am going to use old and new boost graph only for this feature. More over I was told that, such deep copying will increase complexity also as boost graph will be big.  So how to avoid deep copying but also gets our task done ?  But currently I am focusing on deep copying solution.  Let me present with deep copying then I will think of optimization.  ( If you already know optimization please suggest)

Comment: You can avoid deep copying by making sure sharing is safe. First of all stop doing manual memory management. Next up, make the pointers point to immutable objects, that way you *know* you will copy if you need to modify. Shared pointers might add reference counting so you don't have to keep track of when objects can be deleted. Of course in the end it depends on what the object graph (not the boost graph) looks like.

Comment: To be completely honest, it looks as though you are missing a proper domain model of the "schematic". **It** should own all the entities. You could then model a graph _over it_, that doesn't own or contain any more data than just references to the domain model. Of course, you'll have the same immutability requirements under threading. To be honest, the fact that you said "it is crashing after some time" tells me that it's more likely that you didn't get lifetime and owership right than that it's about mutable nodes. But we can't tell without knowing the application model.